# How to print all paths for multi-origin and multi-targets graph using python

Tags: python, graph

I had searched lots of links but still cannot find any example codes to print all paths for multi-origin and multi-target graph.
I tried to use BFS method, but no idea how to set the break function for new paths, can any one give me a simple example showing how to create a multi-origins multi-targets graph? 
Or can you tell me how to change below function so that the 'last' variable is not a single destination point?
Below is the code, thank you for your help:

```
    def findpaths(g: List[List[int]], src: List[int], dst: List[int], v: int) -> None:
      
      # Create a queue which stores the paths
      q = deque()
      
      # Path vector to store the current path
      path = []
      path.append(src)
      q.append(path.copy())
      
      while q:
        path = q.popleft()
        last = path[len(path) - 1] ###?how to make changes?
        
        # If last vertex is the desired destination then print the path
        if (last == dst):  ###I have multiple destination, but how to set the variables?
          printpath(path)
    
        # Traverse to all the nodes connected to current vertex and push new path to queue
        for i in range(len(g[last])):
          if (isNotVisited(g[last][i], path)):
            newpath = path.copy()
            newpath.append(g[last][i])
            q.append(newpath)
```

Comment: can you show sample input for `g`, `src`, `dst`, `v`? also the expected output

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply, I thought no one answered me, the result shows below:\
'g [[371, 123], [371000, 123], [113, 130], [123, 450], [17, 110], [123, 610], [123, 120]...]\
src [371]\
dst [210, 310,  350, 500, 610, 341, 350, 320, 331, 320, 440....]'\
'v' is all the unique numbers in 'g','src','dst', as you may note that there are  lots of duplicates in g and dst, I also need to remove duplicates in g and dst, to get unique value in list, should I use 'set()'?

Comment: so the values you have shown are the inputs? can you also show the output?

Comment: and expected output: ->1. path from src 371 to dst 210 are 
371 123 210
371 123 141 210 
371 123 161 172 210
371  211 189 120 210
2.path from src 371 to dst 310 are .....
Above output is just to show the format, cause I still haven't got all paths printed, so not sure how many paths are they from 371 to 210

Comment: there should be all paths come out from src to each number of dst

Comment: of course, src currently has 371 only, but later it will have other numbers just same format as dst

Comment: are you ok with DFS?

Comment: yes, currently we can have direction from src to dst, but later on all paths are undirected

Comment: I will try if I can solve this

Comment: appreciate your help, I use the BFS, and got error but no idea how to solve, only know the error from the 'last' variable cause there's no path stored in it

Comment: can you provide a complete list of values for `g` and `v` instead of truncating?

Comment: they are out of webpage characters limit, cause they are from my dataset with huge values

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232374/discussion-between-python-user-and-alicia).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a recursive generator that yields all possible paths by doing a Depth First Search (DFS) for all `src`, `dst` pairs in the graph `g`.

```
from itertools import product

def find_path(g, src, dst):
    graph = {}
    res = {}
    for from_, to_ in g:
        graph.setdefault(from_, set()).add(to_)
        graph.setdefault(to_, set()).add(from_) # comment this line for directed graph

    def dfs(src, dst, parents, seen):
        if src in seen:
            return
        if src == dst:
            yield parents + [src]
        seen.add(src)
        for i in graph.get(src, []):
            yield from dfs(i, dst, parents + [src], seen)
        seen.remove(src)

    for source, destination in product(src, dst):
        res[f'{source} to {destination}'] = list(dfs(source, destination, [], set()))

    return res


g = [(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3), (3, 4), (4, 1), (4, 2), (4, 3), (4, 4)]
src = [1, 2, 3, 4]
dst = [1, 2, 3, 4]

print(find_path(g, src, dst))
```

Output

```
{'1 to 1': [[1]],
 '1 to 2': [[1, 2], [1, 3, 2], [1, 3, 4, 2], [1, 4, 2], [1, 4, 3, 2]],
 '1 to 3': [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4, 3], [1, 3], [1, 4, 2, 3], [1, 4, 3]],
 '1 to 4': [[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 4], [1, 3, 2, 4], [1, 3, 4], [1, 4]],
 '2 to 1': [[2, 1], [2, 3, 1], [2, 3, 4, 1], [2, 4, 1], [2, 4, 3, 1]],
 '2 to 2': [[2]],
 '2 to 3': [[2, 1, 3], [2, 1, 4, 3], [2, 3], [2, 4, 1, 3], [2, 4, 3]],
 '2 to 4': [[2, 1, 3, 4], [2, 1, 4], [2, 3, 1, 4], [2, 3, 4], [2, 4]],
 '3 to 1': [[3, 1], [3, 2, 1], [3, 2, 4, 1], [3, 4, 1], [3, 4, 2, 1]],
 '3 to 2': [[3, 1, 2], [3, 1, 4, 2], [3, 2], [3, 4, 1, 2], [3, 4, 2]],
 '3 to 3': [[3]],
 '3 to 4': [[3, 1, 2, 4], [3, 1, 4], [3, 2, 1, 4], [3, 2, 4], [3, 4]],
 '4 to 1': [[4, 1], [4, 2, 1], [4, 2, 3, 1], [4, 3, 1], [4, 3, 2, 1]],
 '4 to 2': [[4, 1, 2], [4, 1, 3, 2], [4, 2], [4, 3, 1, 2], [4, 3, 2]],
 '4 to 3': [[4, 1, 2, 3], [4, 1, 3], [4, 2, 1, 3], [4, 2, 3], [4, 3]],
 '4 to 4': [[4]]}
```